# weird focus problem in pyqt

Tags: pyqt

I have a gui built using QT and Python using pyqt. I use several widgets linked to methods using the usual signal and slots mechanism. For some widgets like certain push buttons or radio buttons (not all of them ..) after I press the button once and everything works as expected, I cannot focus those buttons anymore. When I move the mouse over and try a click a different control is focused instead and receives the click event. I do not understand what could cause such behavior.

Comment: Can you create a short code example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Tried that but the problem cannot be reproduced in a simple experimental application. I am using latest Ubuntu 11.04 which I am afraid comes along with a good load of fresh new bugs but I cannot precisely single out what may be the real cause for this problem.

Comment: The problem is caused by the Ubuntu 11.04 Unity Desktop, it does not reproduce on the classic Gnome Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the Ubuntu 11.04 Unity Desktop, it does not reproduce on the classic Gnome Desktop.